# Configuring gitlab repo within Jenkins job as SCM

Tags: git, jenkins

Under `Source Code Management`, I've selected `Git` and specified the following `URL`.

```
Repository URL: https://gitlab.com/team/repo.git
Failed to connect to repository: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

[rob@client ~]$ git ls-remote -h git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git HEAD
[rob@client ~]$
```

How come I'm receiving `handshake_failure`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in the end, make sure your jenkins user has access to your gitlab repo.

Upload `ssh` key to gitlab for instance, then you'll be able to clone from jenkins.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /home/rob/.jenkins/jobs/Test/workspace
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git
 > git init /home/rob/.jenkins/jobs/Test/workspace # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.com:team/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 73c78ce6b86711b24aca184fcaa796e00a7a1ece (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 73c78ce6b86711b24aca184fcaa796e00a7a1ece
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Finished: SUCCESS
```